# Can I write into an NTFS system from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I have two hard drives, one have Arch Linux and the other one Windows 10, I know I can't write from W10 to linux (although there are applications for that but is not recommended). But what about writing from Linux to W10?

I mean I actually write from Linux to my NTFS external hard drive all the time, but I wanted to ask this just in case that there were some differences between an external hard drive (which is just for storing files) and a normal hard drive which have an OS installed (in this case windows 10).

Comment: NTFS-3G has been stable for more than a decade.  Every major Linux distribution for that amount of time has supported it out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read and write NTFS from Linux.  NTFS has been supported since 2006.  NTFS is a file system, so where the file system resides, internal or external, is irrelevant.